# converter uma lista de string em uma lista de números inteiros

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, lista, int

```
x = ['443' , '552' , '342' , '368' , '9867' , '335' , '9412' , '7436' , '1692' , '85' , '990' , '332' , '8816' , '4567' , '279' , '119' , '2290' , '234' , '9863' , '345' , '230' , '5574' , '230' , '5432']
```

*Como posso converter essa lista em uma nova lista , mas de números inteiros?
E após fazer isso , como percorro essa lista e defino qual o valor máximo , minimo , e também encontro média e mediana, sem utilizar as funções max(), min(), mean(), median() e count().*

Comment: E o que já fez? Em qual parte está com dúvida?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa converter todos as `strings` para inteiros;

Primeira Solução *(convencional)*

```
x = ['123', '456', '789']
valores = []
for val in x:
    valores.append(int(val))
```

Segunda Solução *(list comprehension)*

```
valores = [int(val) for val in x]
```

Média é a soma de todos os valores dividido pela quantidade de valores.

```
media = sum(valores) / len(valores)
```

Mediana é a metade da soma de todos os valores.

```
mediana = sum(valores) / 2
```

Máximo e minimo; utilize a função `sort` para ordenar os valores, assim o primeiro valor sempre sera o menor e o ultimo o maior.

```
valores.sort()
min = valores[0]
max = valores[-1]
```

### Completo

```
x = ['123', '456', '789']
valores = [int(val) for val in x]

media = sum(valores) / len(valores)
print(media)

mediana = sum(valores) / 2
print(mediana)

valores.sort()
min = valores[0] # Primeiro valor da lista
print(min)

max = valores[-1] # Ultimo valor da lista
print(max)
```

#### [Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ojpt0V)

Comment: Só uma ressalva: a mediana não é a metade da soma de todos os valores. [Mais detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/301068/78934).

Comment: faltou também você encontrar o valor máximo e mínimo sem usar as funções.

Comment: @CleomirSantos inclui o que faltava

Comment: para calcular a mediana se a quantidade de elementos for par ou ímpar usa - se a fórmula n+1/2 , onde n é a quantidade de elementos da lista , li sobre isso na wikipedia . Acho que funciona das duas maneiras.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos em partes, primeiro converter todos os valores de string para inteiro, vamos percorrer toda a lista para isso. Convertendo um por um todos os elementos da lista que forem string, exemplo:

```
x = ['11', '14', '152', '987']
novo_x = []
for i in x:
    novo_x.append(int(i))
```

Assim você criou uma nova lista com os mesmos valores porém agora todos são inteiros.

Sobre o maior e menor valor... Sem utilizar o max() e min() você precisará percorrer toda a lista salvando o maior e o menor valor e ir procurando para ver se encontra outro valor maior ou menor que o atual, exemplo:

```
x = [11, 14, 152, 987]
Max = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    if(x[i] > Max):
        Max = x[i]

output: 987
```

A média você pode pegar a soma de todos os valores da lista utilizando sum() dividido pelo total de itens da lista utilizando len()... Ficando:

```
x = [11, 14, 152, 987]
media = sum(x)/len(x)
```

-- edit --

Sobre a mediana... o colega abaixo, Pedro me corrigiu:

A mediana é o valor que separa a metade maior e a metade menor de uma amostra, se essa amostra for par, o exemplo que dei abaixo se aplica, mas se for impar, segue o exemplo que o colega abaixo deu.

```
x = [11, 14, 152, 987]
mediana = sum(x)/2
```

Answer (score 1):

Só uma coisa sobre a resposta aceita: a mediana, segundo a Wikipédia, é *o valor que separa a metade maior e a metade menor de uma amostra, uma população ou uma distribuição de probabilidade*.

Quer dizer, é o elemento do meio da lista se a lista tem um número ímpar de elementos, ou a média dos dois elementos do meio se a lista tem um número par de elementos.

Em código:

```
x = ['443' , '552' , '342' , '368' , '9867' , '335' , '9412' , '7436' , '1692' , '85' , '990' , '332' , '8816' , '4567' , '279' , '119' , '2290' , '234' , '9863' , '345' , '230' , '5574' , '230' , '5432']
valores = list(map(int, x))

if len(valores_ordenados) % 2 == 0:
    mediana = (valores_ordenados[len(valores_ordenados)//2] + valores_ordenados[len(valores_ordenados)//2 - 1])/2
else:
    mediana = valores_ordenados[len(valores_ordenados)//2]
```

Comment: Faltou incluir o numero maior e menor

Comment: @RFL isso já foi respondido em outras respostas; só quis completar o que estava faltando/errado nelas.